# App crashes on emulator but it works on real device

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

So I have an application, which of course have a main layout. This layout have views which then I find them in activity -"findViewById". As usual I first setContentView and then I find views. Strange thing is that app works fine on my real device (Htc Desire 2.3.7 ), and on Samsung Galaxy S3 mini (4.1), but it instantly crashes on emulators -tested on 2.3.5 and 4.1 emulator. The crash problem is very interesting:

```
    10-28 19:39:58.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5183): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-28 19:39:58.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5183): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{wowmemes.iterbit.com/activites.iterbit.com.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-28 19:39:58.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5183):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
10-28 19:39:58.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5183):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
10-28 19:39:58.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5183):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
10-28 19:39:58.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5183):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
10-28 19:39:58.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5183):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-28 19:39:58.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5183):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-28 19:39:58.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5183):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
10-28 19:39:58.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5183):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-28 19:39:58.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5183):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-28 19:39:58.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5183):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
10-28 19:39:58.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5183):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
10-28 19:39:58.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5183):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-28 19:39:58.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5183): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-28 19:39:58.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5183):     at activites.iterbit.com.MainActivity.initializeViewsAndGetPreferences(MainActivity.java:200)
10-28 19:39:58.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5183):     at activites.iterbit.com.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:107)
10-28 19:39:58.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5183):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
10-28 19:39:58.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5183):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
10-28 19:39:58.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5183):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
10-28 19:39:58.718: E/AndroidRuntime(5183):     ... 11 more
```

NullPointerException? What ? I've checked again if maybe I forgot to use "findViewById" method on some of the views, but I didn't. It works great on real device also.

Anyone have ever met similar problem?

Main Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);


    PAPYRUS = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/papyrus.ttf");

    if(!checkIfNetworkAvailable()) {

        new MyCustomDialog(this, R.style.MyDialogStyle, R.layout.network_check, getResources().getString(R.string.networkCheck_Text)).show();
    }
```

selectedCategoriesPreference =getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs",MODE_PRIVATE);

initializeViewsAndGetPreferences();

```
 }


private void initializeViewsAndGetPreferences() {

    recentTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.recent_TV);
    recentTV.setTypeface(PAPYRUS);
    recentTV.setOnClickListener(this);
```

}

Here is my mainLayout xml ( only text view )

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/recent_TV"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
    android:text="Recent" />
```

Comment: what is there at line no 107 and 200 in MainActivity.java

Comment: It's a TextView. This particular code: recentTV.setOnClickListener(this);

Comment: post the code for Mainactivity sir , and please bold above mentioned line numbers

Comment: View probably isn't inflated, show your code.

Comment: what is recentTV exactly?

Comment: I've edited my code. Even if I remove this text view, the problem persists with other views. recentTv is TextView..

Comment: @rootpanthera : given your code, it cannot be at `recentTV.setOnClickListener(this);`. It has to be the line before. `mainLayout` != `main_layout`. also, do you have any alternate layouts?

Comment: with mainLayout i meant this layout i'm using now. (main_layout). Just got a typo. Sorry for that. I've no alternate layouts. Anyway, I've tested this code on the next real device ( Samsung Galaxy Ace - 2.2.1 ) and it also works fine. I don't have an idea why the hell it crashes on emulator, omg.

Comment: Actually I have alternate layouts. Two of them, but for different screen sizes. But views are the same on both of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured out what was wrong..

When testing on real device, screen size on mentioned phones above was medium - xlarge. I had two layouts. One for medium - xlarge devices and one for small devices. When testing on emulator, I was using only small devices, therefore layout for small devices was used. WHen testing on real devices, because of they have large screens, the other layout was pulled.

And what was wrong with the small layout? Well, I'm a dumbass. I've added some new features into my application and I was working on main layout, and completely forgot about small layout. So some views were not existing in small layout. That's why NullPointerException was thrown..